# java Inputstream can't show @

Tags: java, special-characters, inputstream

I have a problem when I use Shell from Jsch to input an address contain a symbol '@',the Inputstream seems can't read this symbol and automatically delete the characters in front of it, like 'oracle@abc' will show in 'abc', here is the code

```
        String in="scp oracle@192.168.1.11:/tempuse/prodexp/sample.dmp ./";
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(in.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        channel.setInputStream(is);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
```

Comment: Enclosing the URL in single quotes may help: `'oracle@192.168.1.11:/tempuse/prodexp/sample.dmp'`, if this is going to be interpreted by a shell. The single quote prevents any further processing of the command-line argument, and @ may have a special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

just founded the answer.
this problem is because of the at sign is a default terminal command for remove line in HP UX or many other UNIX LINUX system.
when you type `stty -a` you would see all of them. for reference below links would help
[the answer I founded](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/System-Administration/At-cmd-prompt-typing-an-at-sign-erases-to-beginning-of-line/td-p/5573715#.Uh1fJT8iByJ)